# Access VBA: many CommandButton execute same code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with many buttons.
Most of these buttons have a .tag field where I identify their function (numeric field)

Every button, on click, should execute same code, passing the .tag value to a function:

```
Private Sub CtlNameA_Click()
   Call WriteTimbraIN(CInt(CtlNameA.tag))
   DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Is there a smarter way to do it without writing the very same code (except for control name) in every button?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a function from the form module directly from the button click events, and use `Screen.ActiveControl` to determine the calling button.

```
Private Function GenericButton()

    Debug.Print "Called from " & Screen.ActiveControl.Name

    Call WriteTimbraIN(CInt(Screen.ActiveControl.Tag))
    DoCmd.Close

End Function
```

And then assign `=GenericButton()` as OnClick event.
You can do this in one go by multi-selecting all buttons and then setting the property.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use *WithEvents*. An example can be found here:

[Create Windows Phone Colour Palette and Selector using WithEvents](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29554/Create-Windows-Phone-Colour-Palette-and-Selector-using-WithEvents.html)

Comment: It's an elegant solution, but Andre's solution is cleaner, thanks